# Customize google Map, show info window by default and hide marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

[image]

I want to customize google map to show multiple customized marker with location address and add Button, so when i click on add button it should perform some action.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read our [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also would you care to share what you've done so far to us?

Answer (score 0):

You can create you infowindows and open

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(your_lat, your_lng)  
 });

my_infoWindow.open(map);
```